# JavaMail mail.smtp.ssl.enable is not working

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail

I read on several sites that, when using the JavaMail API, to set the property `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` to true.  I have some code as follows:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "exchangemail1.example.com");
props.put("mail.from", "myemail@example.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
// I tried this by itself and also together with ssl.enable)
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom();
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "me.at@example.com");  
    // also tried @gmail.com
msg.setSubject("JavaMail ssl test");
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

Transport trnsport;
trnsport = session.getTransport("smtp");
trnsport.connect();
msg.saveChanges(); 
trnsport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
trnsport.close();
```

This sends email, but:

1. when I do traffic capture, I see it is not encrypted
2. When using debug (`props.put("mail.debug", "true")`), I see that "isSSL false"

(I also tried above adding in `props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true")` + user/password....)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

To use SSL you should change your protocol from [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) to [SMTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS) by changing

```
trnsport = session.getTransport("smtp");
```

to

```
trnsport = session.getTransport("smtps");
```

Comment: I was just implementing sending over SSL and when I call session.getTransport("smtps"); it works ok. So this answer is valid.

Comment: This is deprecated, with the message: `The static method send(Message) from the type Transport should be accessed in a static way` Is there a more modern way to specify `smtps`?

Answer (score 7):

Form the [Java Doc](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html):

> Note that if you're using the "smtps" protocol to access SMTP over SSL, all the properties would be named "mail.smtps.*".

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.**ssl.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.**ssl.required", "true");
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using Apache [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/). It has setters for the most used properties (including SSL / TLS) and is more friendlier to use and sits ontop of the JavaMail API.

Update: I was looking at commons-email code, and saw these lines:

```
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", this.tls);
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

so, give these properties a try as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [SSLNOTES](https://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt) document from JavaMail (emphasis added):

> First, and perhaps the simplest, is to set a property to enable use
>   of SSL.  For example, to enable use of SSL for SMTP connections, set
>   the property **"mail.smtp.ssl.enable"** to "true".
>
> Alternatively, you can configure JavaMail to use one of the **SSL-enabled
>   protocol names**.  In addition to the non-SSL JavaMail protocols "imap",
>   "pop3", and "smtp", the protocols "imaps", "pop3s", and **"smtps"** can
>   be used to connect to the corresponding services using an SSL
>   connection.
>
> **-- STARTTLS support**
>
> The STARTTLS support is available in the standard "imap" and "smtp"
>   protocols, but must be enabled by setting the appropriate property,
>   mail.imap.starttls.enable or **mail.smtp.starttls.enable**, to "true".
>   When set, if the server supports the STARTTLS command, it will be
>   used after making the connection and before sending any login
>   information.

So when using the STARTTLS support it seems that it is not necessary to set the protocol to `smtps`.

Comment: According to [The JavaMail README](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/README.txt) using the STARTTLS mechanism requires also using the `smtp` protocol.  This is a little counter-intuitive.  The `smtps` protocol is intended for direct SSL connections that do not require STARTTLS.